# Trying to compare row values, and print a message in anew column for the row that has the highest

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPXq8.jpg

If you look on the far right i was able to do Kinda of what i wanted, but its only comparing European sales to north American sales.

However, I want to compare European sales against the sales in the other columns too (compare it to multiple columns). How can i go about doing this ? not just compare against NA_Sales

Essentially, i want to compare the sales of one columns against them all, and which every has the higher i want it to say that game X sold more in X continent. Thanks

this is the code is used for EU sales against Na sales

```
def desc(row):
    if row['EU_Sales'] > row['NA_Sales']:
        return '{} sold more in europe'.format(row['Name'])

    else:
        return 'nothing'

df1['status'] = df1.apply(desc, axis = 1)
Thanks
```

Also, is there a better way to word this question ? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can try `np.where`

```py
import numpy as np

df1['status'] = np.where(df1['EU_Sales'] > df1['NA_Sales'], df1['Name']+' sold more in europe', 'nothing')
```

You can use `max(axis=1).idxmax()` to get the coresponding column name of max value

```py
df1['status'] = df1['Name'] + ' sold more in ' + df1[['EU_Sales', 'NA_Sales', 'JP_Sales']].idxmax(axis=1).str.split('_').str[0]
```

Comment: I want to compare EU_Sales to the other columns as well, not just NA_Sales. is there efficient  way of doing this ? thanks

Comment: @DOdonnabhain How many columns do you want to generate?

Comment: I just want to create one new column but in each row of it I want it to print out a label that says Name sold more in X continent

Comment: @DOdonnabhain Updated the answer, is this what you want?